# Copy-DbaAgentJob cmd with -Job parameter

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

while using Copy-DbaAgentJob dbatools cmd, what would need to passed to the parameter `Job`

- is it an array with the names of the jobs to be copied
- is it an array of actual jobs from the cmd `Get-DbaAgentJob`

Answer (score 0):

As per `Get-Help Copy-DbaAgentJob`:

```
Copy-DbaAgentJob
    [[-Source] <DbaInstanceParameter>]
    [[-SourceSqlCredential] <PSCredential>]
    [-Destination] <DbaInstanceParameter[]>
    [[-DestinationSqlCredential] <PSCredential>]
    [[-Job] <Object[]>]
    [[-ExcludeJob] <Object[]>]
    [-DisableOnSource]
    [-DisableOnDestination]
    [-Force]
    [[-InputObject] <Job[]>]
    [-EnableException]
    [-WhatIf]
    [-Confirm]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

The `-Job` parameter is an array of objects, but more specifically `Get-Help Copy-DbaAgentJob -Detailed` says:

```
-Job [<System.Object[]>]
    The job(s) to process. This list is auto-populated from the server.
    If unspecified, all jobs will be processed.
```

One of the examples provided by `Get-Help Copy-DbaAgentJob -Examples` also show that you can provide a list of existing jobs from the source server, filtered or otherwise:

```
Get-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance sqlserver2014a |
  Where-Object Category -eq "Report Server" |
  Copy-DbaAgentJob -Destination sqlserver2014b
```